# Rollover Image has an unwanted grey bar under a .png image

Tags: html, image, rollover

I created a rollover image in Photoshop. It was created in a square shape canvas .png. The image is a circle. I created one image normal and one image highlighted as the rollover. The rollover image has an unwanted grey line under it, I don't understand why it is there...

**[EDIT : moved an OP comment to be a question complement]**

– user2773016 1 hour ago

```
<a href="Specification.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('news','','images/ipadjpiGRAYSCALE3.png',1)">
    <img src="images/ipadjpiGRAYSCALE.png" width="350" height="300" id="news" />
</missing closing a tag>
```

Comment: Greetings new user. You are invited to read http://stackoverflow.com/help so you can formulate a decent question with a context, a 'live' example of what you have so far and all material needed to understand your situation.

Comment: As @MilchePatern said some code or some live example would be great to help you out

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.your-element:hover{text-decoration:none}
```

Answer (score 0):

We'd need to see the code it output first in order to help. It could be a number of things off hand. Use jsFiddle or CodePen to make a quick case of what you're talking about. Or if it's small code, post here.

Comment: You should not post 'comments' has an answer.